# Why do some string fields only have a single character when using Oracle heterogeneous services to pull view from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, heterogeneous-services

I have confirmed that the view returns the correct data when on the SQL Server.  But when pulling the raw view through Oracle some of the string columns only contain 1 character for each record, while other columns are fully populated. 
Does anyone know what could cause this issue?

Comment: This can happen when you cast or convert some data to `char`, `varchar`, `nchar` or `nvarchar` and forget to provide a length specifier. e.g.: `cast(999 as char)` instead of `cast(999 as char(10))`. Are you able to provide the code for your view, or at least code for a smaller sample view that also demonstrates the problem?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have access to the actual view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields that had cutoff characters were NVARCHAR(50).  Apparently, Oracle does not pull NVARCHARs correctly from SQL Server.  Casting them as VARCHAR(50) in the SQL Server view solved the problem.